# Python procedimental para Classe problema

Tags: classes, python-3.x, procedural

Estou com problema para transformar uma funcao para uma classe em python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import html2text



# driver.page_source = driver.get())#
def getPEP(strg):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(strg)
    html = driver.page_source
    driver.close()
    text=html2text.html2text(html)
    return(text);

# txt=getPEP('http://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/sample.asp?type=3-Allergy%20/%20Immunology&sample=386-Allergic%20Rhinitis, Allergic Rhinitis')
# print(txt)


peps = open('PEP.txt', 'r')
lines = tuple(peps)
print(lines)
peps.close()
# i=1798 #http://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/sample.asp?type=98-General%20Medicine&sample=487-Request%20For%20Consultation, Request For Consultation
for i in range(len(lines)):
    i=1798
    strg=lines[i].replace('\n','')
    text=getPEP(strg)# print(text)
    start = '#  '
    end = ', \n\n[ ![Join us on'
    cleaned=(text.split(start))[1].split(end)[0]
    # print(cleaned)
    file = open(str(i)+'.txt', 'w')
    file.write(cleaned.replace(' ** ','').replace('**',''))
    file.close()
    # print('arquivo ' + str(i) + ' gravado com sucesso')
```

Criei uma Classe em python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import html2text

class ClassCrawler:

    def __init__(self):
        self.test = self.getPepFromInternt("http://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/sample.asp?type=98-General%20Medicine&sample=487-Request%20For%20Consultation,")
        self.getAllPep('/home/angelica/Documents/gitbucket/mscangelica/dataset/LinksTomtsamples.txt')


    def getPepFromInternt(strg):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get(strg)
        html = driver.page_source
        driver.close()
        text=html2text.html2text(html)
        return(text)

    def getAllPep(linksList):
        peps = open(linksList, 'r')
        lines = tuple(peps)
        print(lines)
        peps.close()
        # i=1798 #http://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/sample.asp?type=98-General%20Medicine&sample=487-Request%20For%20Consultation, Request For Consultation
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            # i=1798 //when the connection is broken 
            strg=lines[i].replace('\n','')
            text= self.getPepFromInternt(strg)# print(text)
            start = '#  '
            end = ', \n\n[ ![Join us on'
            cleaned=(text.split(start))[1].split(end)[0]
            # print(cleaned)
            file = open(str(i)+'.txt', 'w')
            file.write(cleaned.replace(' ** ','').replace('**',''))
            file.close()
```

Porém quando chamo a classe

```
>>> from ClassCrawlerPEP import ClassCrawler
>>> c = ClassCrawler()
```

gera o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/PEPS/ClassCrawlerPEP.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.test = self.getPepFromInternt("http://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/sample.asp?type=98-General%20Medicine&sample=487-Request%20For%20Consultation,")
TypeError: getPepFromInternt() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em Python, o próprio objeto é sempre passado como argumento implícito aos seus respectivos métodos. Por isso, o interpretador reclamou de você ter passado dois argumentos (ele mesmo e a string), mas na definição do método só há um parâmetro.

O que você precisa é apenas declará-lo explicitamente (`self`, segundo o padrão usual, mas pode ser qualquer coisa) como primeiro parâmetro dos métodos da classe:

```
def getPepFromInternt(self, strg):

...

def getAllPep(self, linksList):
```

Comment: Eu ja tinha colocado o self não tinha dado certo, agora deu, isso é algum bug do python? Muito obrigada pela resposta.

Comment: Ele estava acusando o mesmo erro de antes? Se sim, você estava declarando apenas o `self` de parâmetro ou o `strg` também?